# Different settings for git repository of Java EE project with Netbeans

Tags: git, jakarta-ee, netbeans, github

A git repository hosted in github is mainly managed within Netbeans IDE.
If I clone to a new computer, soon after the clean and build, project.properties and private.properties are changed. After committing and pushing these changes to the repository, pulling it from the first project settings have to be changed again. The JPA settings in Persistance.xml and glassfish-resources.xml also have to be changed every-time. 
As a solution, I added those files to the .gitignore, but afterwords cloning a new repository was unidentified as a Netbeans project.

How can I have different settings for different computers?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove these property files from git by doing a rm --cached. This will keep your local copies but will remove them from the repository. Also add them to gitignore so they aren't added in the future. Problem is that when you make changed to the properties, you need to do the same changes on another computer since git will not sync these anymore. I'm having this same problem and no solution.

Your problem is that the files are still in the repository so you still pull them every time. Even if they are in gitignore.